# Search for e-mails with inline pictures in Outlook 2007/2010 advanced search

Tags: microsoft-outlook, images, search

I am aware that there is a way of searching for mail items that have 1 or 2+ attachments within advanced search in the above outlook versions (and probably earlier ones also), however it appears inline pictures in HTML messages are not matched.

As far as I can think / tell, there is only one way available to find these:

`Determine an average e-mail size (in KBytes) for any e-mail with a decent sized image (or indeed other HTML object) in it, and a proportionally smaller amount of text, so one can set a middle ground to search above.`

Has anyone else any other cunning ways to address this?

Comment: Your method seems very hit-and-miss. [Here's a macro](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/saveembeddedpictures.htm) that can extract and save all embedded/inline images. If one can *locate* inline images using VBA, you or someone else should be able to tweak it to search instead of save.

Comment: That's an idea. Thanks for the link. Probably more of _an_ answer though, rather than comment, no? :)

Comment: You're welcome, hope it helps. :) As for it being a valid answer, not really IMO, not unless I had attempted to post at least a workable solution. However I'm short of time right now and cannot look into it, so left it to you or another VBA expert to see if the macro can be suitably modified. If you figure it out, don't forget to self-answer!

Comment: Was hoping for a Outlook UI option / hack, as I am also short on time, but will definitely provide a solution when/if I come up with one (sans someone else's idea working just as well) :)

Answer (score 8):

I found that using Outlook's search box I can filter emails with specific embedded in emails just by stating the extension. Examples of this are.

Look for emails with PNG type pictures => body:png
[PNG type pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJV5k.jpg)

Images sent to the email domain of my support vendor with JPG type images => to:microsoft body:jpg
[Sent to an specific domain with JPG images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGWbq.jpg)

Regards.

Comment: +1 Not exactly answering my question (this isn't in the advanced search; also not the easiest way to search for _any_ image inline in an e-mail if you don't list every possible format of this image), but helpful.